# Java and pass by reference

Tags: java

I'm not terribly familiar with Java, I'm fiddling with a simple binary tree and ran into something that I dont understand...

in the following snippet, `Add()` passes `AddHelper()` a number and a reference to the root node, mRoot. However, mRoot is always null, even after the first call to `AddHelper()`

If, however, I change I change `AddHelper()` such that it uses mRoot directly (instead of being passes in by reference), then it works... I dont understand why/how this would be any different, functionally.

```
Node mRoot;

public void Add( int num ) {
    AddHelper(num, mRoot);
}

private void AddHelper( int num, Node node ){
    // if I change 'node' to 'mRoot', it works. why?
    if ( node == null ) {
        node = new Node(num);
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you have declared  `mRoot` as a `Node` in your class already let me answer your question.

java is always **pass by value** when you pass `mRoot` to your method you are passing bytes that are referring the object in the heap. for example when you do this with a primitive variable

```
int i =5;
int j=i;
```

the bytes stored in `i` is transferred to `j`. similarly when you do this

```
Object obj = new Object();
Object newObj = obj;
```

the bytes stored in the reference variable `obj` is getting transferred to the reference `newObj`. as obj holds the reference to the `Object` instance the same reference is held by `newObj`.

you can see that

```
i = 5;
j=i;
j=10; // this doesn't change the i value
```

same way

```
obj = new Object();
newObj  = obj;
newObj = new Object(); // this doesn't change the obj
```

hope you understood.

**EDIT:**

to answer your question in the comment, consider the following code.

```
class Sample {
  Object originalObj;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println(originalObj); // prints null

   tryToCreateInstance(originalObj);
   System.out.println(originalObj); // still prints null

   createInstance(originalObj)
   System.out.println(originalObj); // prints the object hashcode

  originalObj = returnInstance(originalObj);//returns the same reference as originalObj
                                          //is already initialized, if it had been null
                                          // this would have returned a new object
   System.out.println(originalObj); // prints the object hashcode
  }

  public void tryToCreateInstance(Object obj1){
    if(obj1==null) {
       obj1 = new Object(); // relate this with my answer above 
                            // this wont change what originalObj refers
    }
  }

  public void createInstance(){
    if(obj==null) {
       originalObj = new Object(); // refers to the instance variable originalObj
                                   // hence will affect what originalObj refers
    }
  }

  public Object returnInstance(Object obj1) {
    if(obj1==null) {
       return new Object(); // returns a new object
    }
    else {
      return obj1;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I see... so the whole thing fell apart because I was passing a null object, that by definition points to nothing, and I cannot assign something to nothing. Yes?

Comment: no dats not d fact. you can assign an object to a null reference. check my edited answer

Comment: But you still cannot assign anything to originalObj without assigning an object to it explicitly, that's what I meant. If originalObj is null when it is passed in as a parameter, you cannot assign an object to originalObj _as a parameter_, it remains null. You must in some way have "originalObj = something".

Comment: you are right now... :) glad you understood it.. but _i cannot assign assign something to nothing_ is not right as you can assign an object to a reference that is null.

Comment: sure, I probably could have worded that better :P Thanks!

Comment: Glad that i was of help.. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are not setting `mRoot` in your first case. Even though you are setting a `node` to `new Node(num);`, you are not setting `mRoot`. To set mRoot:

```
if ( node == null ) {
        node = new Node(num);
        this.mRoot = node; //depending on your logic
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
```

Jave is pass by value always. For example, `mRoot` points to Object X. When you pass `mRoot` to `AddHelper`, now `node` will point to Object X. And then you re-initialize `node` to new Object (say Object Y). But the previous `mRoot` still points to Object X.

Hence you need to set `mRoot` back to Object Y.

When we say pass by value, for primitives the value is copied. But in case of Objects, the object reference is copied (but not the object is duplciated). So if you pass a String reference to a function, the function argument will point to the same String only (as it has copied the object reference which can be though of as a pointer)